# Why R dataset takes more memory than Stata dataset written from R but read from Stata

Tags: r, memory, stata

Consider the following R dataset.

```
object.size(mtcars)
6736 bytes

#writing this object as rds

write.rds(mtcar,"mt.rds") 

#properties of the file shows it as 1.218 KB
#reading back rds file

dataRDS<-read.rds("mt.rds")
object.size(dataRDS)
6736 bytes  #this is the same as original mtcars (not surprising)

#writing this object as Stata data

write.dta(mtcars,"mt.dta") 
#clicking the properties of file shows the size as 4.5 KB 
#reading back Stata data in R

dataDTA<-read.dta("mt.dta")
object.size(dataDTA)
8656 bytes 

# this is larger than the original file size

#reading Stata data from Stata gives the size as 2.82 KB


 obs:            32                          Written by R.              
 vars:            11                          
 size:         2,816
```

Why does the default R object take more memory when reading from R than reading the same dataset in Stata which was converted into Stata data from R?

Comment: This is the small dataset for reproducibility only. I am actually dealing with the dataset that is taking large memory in r but not in Stata. Just trying to see what is going here, nothing more.

Comment: In R, all the variables in mtcars are numeric (doubles). If you convert several of them to integers the size is reduced. Two of the columns have only two values and could be stored as logicals, saving even more memory. I don't see row names in the dta version for Stata; removing them saves even more memory. The answer: they are different pieces of software using different data formats and hence there will be differences.

Comment: this question reminded me of [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/it-is-time-for-rdata-files-to-become-the-standard-for-data-transfer/) related post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of it seems to be a difference in the size of the `attributes`, you can see they are stored differently.  And comparing sizes,

```
> object.size(attributes(dataDTA)) - object.size(attributes(dataRDS))
1696 bytes

> object.size(dataDTA) - object.size(dataRDS)
1920 bytes
```

The difference might be due to `object.size` being an estimate of the true size.

Comment: Thanks @LegalizeIt. The question is : Is it always the case that Stata takes less memory that R for the same dataset.

Comment: I would imagine so, because R stores all of the attributes associated with a `data.frame`, but I don't know anything about how Stata works.  It looks like Stata is telling you the size of just the data, something like `Reduce(`+`, sapply(dataDTA, object.size))` maybe.

Comment: actually, that is what Stata is doing, you can check.  `mtcars` has dimensions 32*11, so its size if each cell is 8 bytes, would be 32*11*8 = 2816.

Comment: @user227710 The Stata environment is essentially limited to a single rectangular data set, and I'm sure they've optimized memory usage for that case. Score one for Stata, I guess.

Comment: @Frank: Thanks. It may be. Legalizelt: Thanks.